# Memory Required for SSH-only Linux Setup

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine, sshd, distributions

I am attempting to set up a minimal Debian or CentOS installation for internal network access.

The purpose of the setup will be to allow SSH access into the rest of the internal network—**that's it**. It will not need to serve any other function and will have very few additional utilities installed.

For clarity, here is the primary usage scenario for the installation:

1. SSH into this machine from outside of the network.
2. SSH out **from this machine** to the target machine on the internal network

**My questions are:**

- What is the ***minimum amount of memory*** required without running into stability or performance issues?
- How much ***additional memory*** should be reserved to later harden the machine with *AppArmor* or other hardening agents?
- Is there another distro (*Linux* or *BSD*) that would be better suited for this kind of application?

**Additional Considerations:**

- The machine must run with *minimal* resources ( **128 MiB RAM max** )
- *sshuttle* may be used frequently to access the machine
- The ssh server and client will be *OpenSSH*

---

***Note:*** A more distro-oriented version of this question was posted here:
[Lightweight SSH-only distro (< 128 MiB RAM)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171762/87443)

---

Comment: The best way to find out would be to test it out in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that 128 MB is more than enough if you're only going to use SSH and AppArmor. I remember Debian taking up less than 64 MB of RAM with just SSH and an Asterisk PBX started.

Edit: As of 8 June 2020, due to general software bloat, nowadays you're going to need 256 MB of RAM in order to run a barebones Linux with nothing but SSH and AppArmor. You might be able to cut down on RAM usage if you use Gentoo and build a manually configured kernel (i.e. not with genkernel).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a particular mainstream distro, the minimal amount of RAM recommended for that distro is enough.

Things like OpenWRT or uCLinux can run on  *single megabytes* of RAM, on a box like your old router from 10 years ago, still comfortably providing SSH access (usually via dropbear and busybox).